# Error message when using Method -> "Spline" in Interpolation

Tags: warning-messages, interpolation

I'm using the code:

```
time = Table[i, {i, 0, 2042, 10.87}];
I1 = Table[Exp[-((i - 1000)^2)/(250)^2], {i, 0, 2042, 10.87}];
I1time = Table[{time[[i]], 10^3 I1[[i]]}, {i, 1, Length[time]}];

I1spline = Interpolation[I1time, Method -> "Spline"]
Int[sx_, sy_] := 
  NIntegrate[I1spline[x] Exp[- (sx + I sy) x], {x, 0, 20}];

sxmin = 0; sxmax = 50; sxInc = 0.5;
symin = -50;  symax = 50; syInc = 0.5; 

DiscreateLT = 
  Flatten[Table[{{sx, sy}, Int[sx, sy]}, {sx, sxmin, sxmax, 
     sxInc}, {sy, symin, symax, syInc}], 1];

LTNOspline = Interpolation[DiscreateLT, Method -> "Hermite"]
```

This works fine, and generates the function `LTNOspline` with no problems. But it is not accurate enough for my problem, so I want to use the Spline method instead.  However, when I change

```
LTNOspline = Interpolation[DiscreateLT, Method -> "Hermite"]
```

for

```
LTNOspline = Interpolation[DiscreateLT, Method -> "Spline"]
```

in my code, I get the error message

> Interpolation::mspl: The Spline method could not be used because the data could not be coerced to machine real numbers.

Any suggestions about how to use the spline interpolation without the error message?

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24800/correct-use-of-listinterpolation

Comment: My suggestion is to use `{sx, sy, Int[sx, sy]}` as the 1st argument to `Table` in the definition of `DiscreateLT`. I have no way of checking this idea because you don't give all the code needed to duplicate your work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your data is complex and ( I guess) the spline method cannot handle complex numbers.
You can separately fit the real and imaginary parts like this:

```
LTNOsplineRe = 
 Interpolation[MapAt[Re, DiscreateLT, {All, 2}], Method -> "Spline"]
LTNOsplineIm = 
 Interpolation[MapAt[Im, DiscreateLT, {All, 2}], Method -> "Spline"]
LTNOspline = 
 Function[{x, y}, LTNOsplineRe[x, y] + I LTNOsplineIm[x, y]]
```

Comment: I've implemented your above suggestion and now my code works! Thanks! As you suggested, it would seem that the "Spline" method cannot handle complex data